# Custom toolbar to back press icon and function in fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, toolbar, onbackpressed

I have created one fragment *mybillList.java* with mutliple list. After i clicking any item, it will move to *mybillDetails.java*.

I don't want drawer menu on *mybillDetails.java*.In this fragment, i need back press icon(with function) instead of drawer menu.

[image: mybillList.java]

mybillList.java

I have tried `getSuppotActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

[image]

mybillDetails.java

Comment: I included the image in the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant closing the activity when clicked back button in action bar, try this

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

if not, add some stuff instead of `finish()`.

Comment: Thanks, But its open navigation drawer instead of back{ finish(); }

Comment: Then do other thing instead of `finish()`, do you know what i mean?

Comment: yeah, I know. while debugging these code are not calling

Comment: Please tell one thing... whether R.id.home points drawer or back icon??

Comment: Back icon in mybillDetails.java

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help you...

```
 mActionBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            OnBackPressed();
        }
    });
```